# iOS 8 simulator not clearing user defaults on deleting the app in Xcode 6.0?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode6, nsuserdefaults

The user defaults are not cleared on deleting an app in XCode 6 iOS 8 simulator. The user defaults are cleared only on resetting the simulator. In iOS 7 simulator, this is not a problem at all. Any other solution rather than resetting the simulator?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I guess his question would be "Is this a bug, and if not, what am I doing wrong?"

Comment: Wasn't this fixed in Xcode 6.1?

Comment: I think this fixed in Xcode 6.1 and simulator iOS 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i too observed that in iOS 8 simulator ...do this for clearing NSUserDefaults data.

iOS Simulator ---> Reset Content and Settings… ---> Ok

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the iOS 8.0 simulator runtime as mentioned in multiple other posts here on Stack Overflow, Apple's Dev Forums, and the [Xcode 6 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html) which indicate that the issue is fixed in the iOS 8.1 simulator runtime.

> Deleting an app from iOS Simulator now deletes user defaults as
>   expected. (18307910)

Answer (score -1):

Clear the /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData folder.

Also reset the simulator. And clean and build the Xcode.

Hope this may help you.